# Почему числу с плав точкой можно присвоить целочисленное значение?

Tags: c#

```
float val = 10;
//а не float val = 10.0f;
```

Ведь по умолчанию целочисленным значениям даётся тип int, short и тд(в зависимости от размера). А с плав точкой по умолчанию double.
А если мы хотим изменить тип по умолчанию просто указываем суффикс в конце числа. Тогда почему можно не указывать при присвоении целочисл типа к типу с плав точкой?

Comment: Потому что если вы слева от знака присваивания указали тип переменной, то будет сделано неявное преобразование типа выражения справа к типу слева. Но не для всех типов данных это работает, некоторые нужно явно преобразовывать.

Comment: Потому что компилятор знает оба типа и значение справа. Он понимает что целое значение *10* может быть преобразовано в вещественное значение *10.f* без потери информации. Для удобства программиста компилятор делает это преобразование. Если бы справа стояло значение слишком большое или неизвестное компилятору (например целая переменная), то компилятор выдал бы предупреждение или ошибку что данные могут быть потеряны при приведении.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/single.cs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в том, что если тип `T` можно **без потерь** преобразовать в тип `T2`, то скорее всего существует **неявное преобразование** `T2(T v)`. При преобразовании `int` в `float` никакие данные не теряются (любое число, которое можно представить в виде `int` можно так же представить в виде `float`). Однако `float` в `int` неявно преобразовать не получится, для этого существует **явное преобразование**:

```cs
int x = (int)4.5f
```

При преобразовании `float` в `int` мы теряем дробную часть, поэтому нам необходимо явно указать, что мы осознаём все потери и готовы пойти на них.

[Вы так же можете определить явное и неявное преобразование для своих типов](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators)

Comment: `любое число, которое можно представить в виде int можно так же представить в виде float` - это не совсем так, у float всего 23 бита мантиссы, и некоторые целые числа не могут быть точно представлены во float

Comment: @MBo Ну тут уже вроде как будет исключение о переполнении... Не стал об этом писать что бы не перегружать информацией

Comment: Нет, это не переполнение, и исключения никакого не будет.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Хм и вправду, ради интереса проверил и получил `2147483600` вместо `2147483647`... При этом ошибки не было... Хотя возможно это проблема вывода, ну ка дайте я кое что проверю

Comment: @MBo При преобразовании `2147483647` к float получаю `2147483648`... Значит никаких потерь нет. Видимо для положения точки во float выделяется больше памяти... Попробую ещё поэксперементировать

Comment: Еденичку потеряли) или ошиблись, 47 и 48

Comment: @gachi_muchenik Неа, такой вывод... Я вот что заметил, для больших `int` `float` просто равен размеру `int` если его выводить через формат `F`

Comment: `ToString('F'): 2147483648,00;
ToString('0'): 2147484000;
int: 2147483647`
Похоже тут форматирование постаралось
`ToString('F'): 2147483648,00;
ToString('0'): 2147484000;
int: 2147483642`

Comment: @ШвеевАлексей Дело в том, что float числа распределены неравномерно. В диапазоне от 1.0 до 2.0 находится 16 миллионов чисел. И в диапазоне  от 2 до 4 - тоже 16 миллионов, ... и в диапазоне от 16 миллионов до 32 миллионов - тоже, здесь все вещественные совпадают с целыми, а вот в диапазоне от 32 миллиона до 64 миллионов целых чисел - 32 миллиона, а вещественных по-прежнему 16 миллионов, половину целых нельзя перевести во float, и дальше тоже float идут реже целых.